# Local asp.net installation - SQL Server Express, IISExpress

Tags: asp.net, iis-express, sql-server-2008r2-express

I have an ASP.NET project that I run on localhost with a SQL Server 2008 R2 Express. I want to make a setup with all that i need to install in client's PC, and automate it in a way that I do not need to configure the SQL Server Express (like creating the databases, users, membership, etc).

What's the best way to do that ? I've searched a few applications that generate a setup file (like Installshield, but free), but my main question is how do I make a setup of SQL Server 2008 R2 Express with all configuration needed, without prompting for input ?

Another problem is how to make the IIS Express run when I open the website ? I want to make it as similar as a .exe app (maybe site-specific website). What's the best way ?

EDIT:

I've made a batch script like :

> start iisexpress.exe /site:xpto
>
> start http:/localhost/xpto

Is this the best way? Any suggestions ?

Regards

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 is **commercial software** - I don't think you can just install that like that with your software....

Comment: You could use aspnet_regsql.exe, but this would prompt for entering information. Another way is to write a powershell script which sets up the database and all.

Comment: ok i'll check how powershell script works. What about launching the website & the iis express at same time ?